# Alternative "float: left" in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float

I use flexbox and in the same way I use “float: left”.
My mentor said that I should avoid “float: left”.
What is alternative “float: left” in flexbox?

I will be glad to hear any advice.

Comment: Hi Anton. Can you include a design showing what you're attempting to accomplish? In addition, it would be handy if you distill your CSS and relevant HTML into a small snippet showing how you're using `float: left`, and show where you'd like to move to Flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a look full manual of Flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ this may you help.

"order" property working as "float" if using it with pair of "align-self"

Answer (score 1):

Can can do this also with align-self:flex-end;

if you need more details, you can take a look at more details [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)